# are there any advantages for CRC when compared with 2 dimentional parity?

Tags: crc, parity, dimensional

are there any advantage for CRC when compared with 2 dimensional parity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with CRC, you can detect "burst" errors, that is any sequence of errors.
CRC uses fewer bits. 
with CRC you can correct one bit errors.

2 dim parity you can detect 1, 2 and 3 bit errors and sometimes 4 bit errors
4 bit errors that are not detected are ones on 4 corners (forming a rectangle)